# Best DNN approach for datasets without spatial structure

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

I have a clinical dataset that consists of 5 independent test results and a truth (diagnosis) flag for each sample. The feature vector is 830,000 x 5; i.e. 830,000 samples x 5 tests.

Using 75% of the data for training, I have successfully evaluated a multinomial logistic regression (84.4% accuracy), weighted k-nearest neighbor (90.4%), DNN w/ 2 hidden 512 neuron layers (84.1%), and a CNN (86.9%).

Theoretically, my understanding is that there should be no advantage to the CNN with spatially (or temporally) unstructured data, yet it has the 2nd best accuracy while the DNN has the worst.

I would like to implement the DNN "correctly", i.e. go beyond the default model I started with and use the optimal number of layers and neurons. How would I determine this for my data set?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1):

Hold your horses with DNN :)

You have only 5 features (5 test results) per test, right. Do you have any prior knowledge of how test results relate or structure? I.e. you can exploit some correlation structure and it should be pretty simple to enumerate in the simplest case.

You can try to preprocess with PCA first before a linear classifier. Perhaps the largest variance directions in 5D space are discriminative.

Then you can try a Linear Discriminant Analysis. This should take into account inter class covariances and between the classes, all while separating the classes. My guess is that this might work pretty well on your data as you will be learning 5x5 matrices and you have so many samples.

I suggest to try random forests classifier or an SVM classifier with different kernels as your first picks from non-linear classifiers. That should be very fast to train and evaluate.

My reasoning against DNN here is that there can be too little of structure with 5 features to exploit. A simpler classifier should fare here well.

Also, try to split your dataset into train, validation and testing. Compare the algorithms only on the test set. Touch it only once.

Of course, you can do DNN, nobody will forbid you. :) If you insist, in your case I would go only with 1 hidden layer (max 2 or 3).